# Does Ethereum Suffer From Transaction Malleability?

Tags: transactions, security, cryptography

Does Ethereum in its current form (Homestead, specifically Geth v1.3.6) have transaction malleability issues similar to Bitcoin? If so, is there a standard method for deriving a normalized hash for Ethereum transactions?

> Transaction Malleability = The ability for a node on the network to change a transaction in a way such that the hash is invalidated. This produces an identical transaction with a different hash, causing issues for nodes that store and query transactions by hash.

In the past it seems this was an issue/concern. I'm just wondering if it still is or if it has been addressed.

**HISTORY**

Vitalik mentions susceptibility to transaction malleability on reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3o9ru0/transaction_malleability_does_ethereum_have_this/

EIP-2 (Homestead Fork) also involved transaction malleability fixes: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki

Comment: can you define transaction malleability?

Comment: @VoR0220 Went ahead and fleshed out transaction malleability meaning. Also added links to relevant historical material for Ethereum.

Comment: Do you mean "the ability for a node [...] to change a transaction in a way such that the hash _isn't_ invalidated"? It's easy to change a transaction and invalidate the hash.

Comment: @NickJohnson I do not. So transaction malleability in Bitcoin actually makes it so the same transaction can appear with a different hash, wreaking havoc on systems that look up transactions by hash as the same transaction can appear to be multiple transactions. They've developed normalized hashes in order to mitigate this.

Comment: @EricScrivner But changing a transaction so the hash is invalid is trivial, and useless. I think at the least you need to clarify what you meant - it sounds like "producing an identical transaction with a different hash".

Comment: The link to EIP-2 is now https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.md (the extension is different)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it does not suffer from malleability (anymore). The homestead hardfork included the malleability fix and transactions that have their signature in the upper range of `secp256k1n/2` are rejected.