# What is the purpose of OpenZeppelin ECDSA.sol contract?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, library, ecdsa

what is the purpose of the ECDSA contract ( https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol ) ?

Contract looks like  a wrapper around builtin solidity ecrecover  function, without any benefits, or I've missed something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the code you will realize it provide some niceties:

- Checking for malleable signatures
- Support for 64 bytes compact signatures
- Signature message manipulation, adding Ethereum signature prefix
- Helper for [EIP 712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) signatures

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

Could you please add a bit more details to make the answer more clear 

`Checking for malleable signatures`

As far as I know, malleable signatures are not possible in Geth since homestead https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/does-ethereum-suffer-from-transaction-malleability  . Am I missing something ?

`prepending a prefix`

Prefix is prepended in Geth  by default for data signing operations 

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d8ff53dfb8a516f47db37dbc7fd7ad18a1e8a125/accounts/accounts.go#L195

Comment: `Support for 64 bytes compact signatures`

What exactly do you mean? `ecrecover` works the same way, with    64 bytes compact signatures

`Signature message manipulation, adding signature prefix`
what's the difference  with `Checking for malleable signatures, prepending a prefix` ?

Comment: @alex For backward compatibility the EVM accepts old signatures. Ecrecover only accept 65 bytes signatures. The prefix part shouldn't have been part of the first sentence, I've updated that line.